# PDO Connection error vs SQL Error, how to detect

Tags: php, pdo

I regularly send copies of WordPress data to a more structure in a Cloud SQL Database (a single woo order in a single row instead of multiple tables) for the benefits of reporting and backups etc.

Im now creating a component that will write the same data to a local copy of the Cloud DB in case there is a network error as a backup which can then be inserted at a later date once the connection is restored.

Im trying to distinguish the difference between a connection error and an SQL error. If I have a connection error then I can use the local copy, if there is an SQL error then I can write the error to a log file as the statement wouldn't work anyway.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
try {
    //Connect to the DB
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->servername;dbname=$this->database",$this->u,$this->p,[
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    => $this->ck,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => $this->cc,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA     => $this->sc,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false
        ]
    );
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $statement = 'INSERT BLA BLA BLA';

    $statement->execute();

}

//Log any errors. However, at this point I would like to drill down into the error to find out if its a connection error or an sql error!
catch(PDOException $e) {

//DcgsqlErrorLog(Object name, Object ID, PDO Error message))
new DcgsqlErrorLog('Product',$this->product->get_id(),$e->getMessage());
    
}

//Close connection and return
finally {
    
    $connection = null;
    return;
}
?>
```

Comment: Place the commands into two separate `try - catch` blocks?

Comment: Connection in one and statement in the other. Sounds good, Ill put the connection in my construct and then I can change the connection vars to the local DB from t here and keep the statement the same. 
Add that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm not sure... it seems kind of trivial for an answer. I'll snoop around some more, see if there's any "fancy" alternative to add some "meat" to it.